# How to remove the inner properties from JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js

I have two JSON stringified objects,

```
var first='{"AdmissionId":254625,"PhysicianId3":null,"VerbalStartOfCareDate":"","PhysicianId2":null,"LatestStatusCode":"A01","ReferralSource":97664,"PhysicianId1":97670,"$id":"2","LatestAdminSetId":90,"LastModified":"2015-03-16T10:13:55.827","AdmitDate":"2015-03-01T00:00:00","TeamId":153,"ProspectAdmitDate":null,"TerminationDate":null,"PatientId":154112,"PatientStatus":[{"Notes":null,"PpsTherapyVisits":null,"SyncEpisodes":null,"StatusCode":"A01","StatusId":0,"PpsEpisodeNo":1,"StatusEndDate":null,"PrimaryDiagnosisId":870428,"Sequence":2,"PpsAssessDate":null,"PatientId":154112,"Acuity":"Pend","SyncStatus":4,"LastModified":null,"BranchId":null,"PpsAssessRfa":null,"PrintDischargeSummary":null,"OasisMatchingKey":null,"PpsScicOverride":null,"PpsKnownLupa":null,"DataSetId":26,"AdminSetId":90,"MsaCode":"50094","GenerateFinalClaimOnly":null,"PpsEpisodeNoModified":"N","AssociatedFacilityRoleId":null,"ClassEndDate":null,"PpsHippsCode":null,"PpsHippsValidity":null,"PatientClass":"HH","ClientId":0,"PpsAssessmentId":null,"StatusTime":null,"HpcanysCareLocation":null,"PpsHhrgId":null,"EpsHhrgId":null,"Id":0,"$id":"3","StatusDate":"2015-08-17T00:00:00","AdmissionId":254625,"PpsNrsSeverityId":null,"AssociatedFacilityId":null}],"CaregiverCode":"SP","ReferralSourceRoleId":33149,"ClinicalSetId":93,"PatientAdmissionCtiDef":null,"Id":0,"SnfIndicator":null,"ClientId":0,"AdmissionCode":null,"ProspectTermDate":null,"SyncStatus":2,"Sequence":1}';

var second = '{"AdmissionId":254625,"PhysicianId3":null,"VerbalStartOfCareDate":null,"PhysicianId2":null,"LatestStatusCode":"A01","ReferralSource":97664,"PhysicianId1":97670,"$id":"2","LatestAdminSetId":90,"LastModified":"2015-03-16T10:13:55.827","AdmitDate":"2015-03-01T00:00:00","TeamId":153,"ProspectAdmitDate":null,"TerminationDate":null,"PatientId":154112,"PatientStatus":[{"Notes":null,"PpsTherapyVisits":null,"SyncEpisodes":null,"StatusCode":"A01","StatusId":802577,"PpsEpisodeNo":1,"StatusEndDate":null,"PrimaryDiagnosisId":870428,"Sequence":1,"PpsAssessDate":null,"PatientId":154112,"Acuity":"Pend","SyncStatus":2,"LastModified":"2015-03-16T10:11:26.857","BranchId":null,"PpsAssessRfa":null,"PrintDischargeSummary":null,"OasisMatchingKey":null,"PpsScicOverride":null,"PpsKnownLupa":null,"DataSetId":26,"AdminSetId":90,"MsaCode":"50094","GenerateFinalClaimOnly":null,"PpsEpisodeNoModified":"N","AssociatedFacilityRoleId":null,"ClassEndDate":null,"PpsHippsCode":null,"PpsHippsValidity":null,"PatientClass":"HH","ClientId":0,"PpsAssessmentId":null,"StatusTime":null,"HpcanysCareLocation":null,"PpsHhrgId":null,"EpsHhrgId":null,"Id":0,"$id":"3","StatusDate":"2015-03-01T00:00:00","AdmissionId":254625,"PpsNrsSeverityId":null,"AssociatedFacilityId":null}],"CaregiverCode":"SP","ReferralSourceRoleId":33149,"ClinicalSetId":93,"PatientAdmissionCtiDef":null,"Id":0,"SnfIndicator":null,"ClientId":0,"AdmissionCode":null,"ProspectTermDate":null,"SyncStatus":2,"Sequence":1}';
```

I need to remove the following properties from the above mentioned JSON objects and the result of that should be compared:

I used underscore's _.omit () functionality it removed only the outer collection property but it failed to remove the inner collection property
eg: `PatientStatus.StatusId` in the above JSON

I also tried using `delete` keyword of javascript it is working, but is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: If you want to use js methods from the underscore lib, you should first parse the string with JSON.parse() before feeding it to the method.

Comment: Why not just set `first.PatientStatus.StatusId = undefined;`

Comment: Right, properties with `undefined` as their value will not be included in the result of `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: Thank you for the solutions. I still have eight properties that need to be removed before comparing the two JSON objects. Is there any other concise solutions other than setting undefined to all the properties which need to be removed ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to `JSON.parse` the string, and then `delete` the property you want to remove..

[JS Delete - Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Comment: I already used this steps.
Is there any other concise solutions to do this ?

Comment: This didn't work for you? It should really work. Can you post a jsfiddle to work on it?

Comment: The above answer that you provided was already tried by me. And it works.
Is there any concise solution other than this ?

Comment: I don't think so. You can iterate on your original object and only copy the properties you want to a new one.. But this is probably a performance killer..